# Удаление множество объектов без зависания

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене более 1к объектов - возможно ли по 1 удалять без провисаний?

```
 var gameOjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
                foreach (var gameOject in gameOjects)
                {
                    if (!gameOject.GetComponent<uLinkNetworkView>() && !ts.Contains(gameOject.name))
                    {
                        gameOject.SetActive(false);
                    }
                    //File.AppendAllText("file.txt", Environment.NewLine + gameOject.name);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых, вы их не удаляете, а лишь выключаете.

Во-вторых, закомментированная вами строчка - вообще убийца производительности.

В-третьих, если вы каждый кадр выполняете это, то поиск объектов по тэгу тоже будет сильно влиять на производительность.

А теперь про оптимизацию:

Как вариант, вы можете спрятать все свои объекты внутри объекта-контейнера. Когда вам понадобится выключить свои объекты, просто выключаете родительский. Это должно работать быстрее.

Если же вам нужно удалять объекты, то нужно пользоваться методом `Destroy`: [тык](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

Для увеличения скорости удаления вы также можете спрятать все свои объекты под один родительский и удалять лишь его.

Если же вам действительно необходимо удалять/скрывать объекты с такими проверками, то сделайте это за несколько кадров:

```
public class Deactivator : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject[] gameObjectsToDeactivate;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    private static const int deletePerFrame = 100;

    public void Start() {
        gameObjectsToDeactivate = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
    }

    public void Update() {
        int remainingThisFrame = deletePerFrame;
        for (; currentIndex < gameObjectsToDeactivate.Length &&
            remainingThisFrame > 0; ++currentIndex) {

            var go = gameObjectsToDeactivate[currentIndex];
            if (!go.GetComponent<uLinkNetworkView>()) {
                go.SetActive(false);
            }
            remainingThisFrame--;
        }
        if (currentIndex >= gameObjectsToDeactivate.Length) {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Как-то так. Кидаете этот скрипт на какой-то объект в сцене, этот скрипт поудаляет все, что вам нужно, а потом самоуничтожится. Таким способом, как мне кажется, тормозить должно не сильно. Вы можете настраивать переменную `deletePerFrame` как вам нужно.

Однако если вы делаете это сразу после загрузки сцены, мне кажется, что пользователь может и подождать секунду-другую, пока вы сделаете все манипуляции.

Напомню: `FindObjectsOfType` работает оооочень медленно, так что если вы хотите удалить объекты за несколько кадров, вызывайте `FindObjectsOfType` лишь в первом.

И да, все остальные вызовы, предполагающие поиск или рефлексию, будут медленными, так что старайтесь их избегать.

Comment: проверка проводиться 1 раз - засунуть под 1 объект нет возможности

Comment: @Sector32 а объекты у вас одного типа? Если не секрет, то что это за объекты, и что за имена появляются в `ts`?

Comment: на ts не обращайте внимания - это я тестировал.Мне нужно удалять карту и камни со сцены дабы заспавнить свою

Comment: @Sector32 хорошо, что за карта и камни, а точнее, откуда они берутся, кто их создаёт? (Я интересуюсь, ибо может быть можно выбрать совсем другой подход).

Comment: я модифицирую готовую игру 2013 года прошенную разрабами - цель удалить все стандартные объекты при загрузке сцены и установить свою через загрузку из бандла

Comment: @Sector32 А возможности удалить объекты в эдиторе из сцены нет?

Comment: я же говорю, что модифицирую готовую игру - исходников нету (

Comment: @Sector32 тогда самый лучший способ - удалять за несколько кадров, добавлю в ответ как это сделать

Comment: хорошо спасибо - жду.

Comment: @Sector32 Обновил ответ. Это растянет процесс удаления объектов на несколько кадров, но избавит от фризов во время удаления. Но как я уже написал в ответе, пользователь ведь может подождать, пока вы сделаете со сценой все, что нужно...

Comment: `GetComponent` в `Update`. Вот это убийца производительности.

Comment: @Suvitruf я уже писал про генерики, но что делать, если того требует задача?

Comment: @selya моя задача просто удалить все со сцены,чтобы установить свое - loading screen у меня есть если что